# YouTrack. Кавычки в поле workflow rule

Tags: youtrack

У меня в задаче есть поле, содержащее кавычки ("Example" field).

Я написал workflow , где в одном из условий содержится это поле.
"Example" field == {Да};
Workwol editor на данную строку не ругается, но при попытке отправить этот workflow на сервер, выдаёт ошибку: 
"Upload workflows.
Error while loading script for rule"

Как мне можно заменить кавычки в workflow rule?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

К сожалению, поле, содержащее кавычки в его имени, в воркфлоу использовать нельзя.